# Can't scan with Simple Scan

Tags: scanner

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1, I tried to scan a document.

The Document Scanner recognizes the existence of the scanner, but issues a caveat (INVALD ARGUEMENT) and terminates.  It will not scan any documents.  Meanwhile, the scanner issues a caveat (SCANNING TO COMPUTER) and has to be “rebooted” to go back to an idle state.

I have never had a problem with Simple Scan on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, or 18.04, but now, on 20.04, it refuses to work.  Any advice would be appreciated.  (I have no problem printing.  Scanner is an HP mw180)

Answer (score 0):

A utility that has been a great success for many users with a modern scanner is [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan). The file you want to install is [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/).

If it works for you, I would be very interested in the outputs you get for `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`. It would help other users.

Comment: Gwen Walcott has no need to respond. A more co-operative user has supplied the requested information and confirmed that sane-airscan works with this device.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had seen this question and the response sooner.  I had the same problem and reported it here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade HP Envy 5640 scanner stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266353/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-hp-envy-5640-scanner-stopped-working/1286645#1286645)

The problem went away when I upgraded to 20.10 last week, so I don't think I can provide any useful outputs for debugging purposes.  But do say if there is anything I can do which would be helpful here.